# Importing the current project as a module in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, pycharm

I'm trying to import the current module(project directory) into a number of files. I have an **__init__.py** file in the project directory:

```
import os
import platform

from flask import Flask, g

app = Flask(__name__)

__all__ = ["server", "database_helpers"]

if platform.system() == 'Windows':
    app.config.update(dict(
        DATABASE=os.path.join(app.root_path, 'database\database.db'),
        SCHEMA=os.path.join(app.root_path, 'database\database.schema')
    ))
elif platform.system() == 'Linux':
    app.config.update(dict(
        DATABASE=os.path.join(app.root_path, 'database/database.db'),
        SCHEMA=os.path.join(app.root_path, 'database/database.schema')
    ))
else:
    print('Unsupported operating system')

from app import server
from app import database_helpers


@app.teardown_appcontext
def close_database_connection(error):
    if hasattr(g, 'db'):
        g.db.close()
```

Upon running the file the following error is thrown:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Project/app/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from app import server
ImportError: No module named app

Process finished with exit code 1
```

where app is the directory in which all python scripts are located. The layout of the project is as follows:

[image: current project directory]

Answer (score 0):

try setting the Enviroment variable 
PYTHONPATH to point to the directory containing app

you can just run in cmd

```
setx PYTHONPATH "C:/Project/"
```

(replace C:/Project/ if it is not the directory that contain "app")

Comment: I added the directory to the environment variable but the same error is thrown

Answer (score 0):

should modify

```
from app import server
from app import database_helpers
```

to

```
import server
import database_helpers
```